# Error ActionScript3: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: CheckBox

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

Well i am having some troubles while trying to use some components from another class.!

I have an array thats type is CheckBox. This Class CheckBox is from another module project that i have imported to my project. It was working perfectly first time i executed, but now, its not working anymore...

`//class scope`

private var _combinationArray:Array.CheckBox;

//constructor scope

_combinationArray = new Array.CheckBox();

_combinationArray[0] = _checkBoxPvrtc;
_combinationArray[1] = _checkBoxEtc1;
_combinationArray[2] = _checkBoxDxt15;

When i execute my program, i get this error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: CheckBox. The error point exactly for this line  `private var _combinationArray:Array.CheckBox;`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't specify a base type for arrays. Just leave out the `.CheckBox`.

Comment: but in the first time that i executed, worked perfectly... if i remove .CheckBox the program executes without the error, but doesnt work properly.

Comment: maybe, its my algorithm... working it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private var _combinationArray:Vector.<CheckBox>;`

`_combinationArray = new Vector.<CheckBox>();`

Should do. It's just that Array is strictly untyped, while Vector is strictly typed.

Comment: work also, but i realized that the problem its with my algorithm!